# RegEx for matching specific URLs with lowercase and dashes

Tags: ios, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

Every morning, I visit this website called mtonews.com and I’m trying to build an iOS shortcut with RegEx to open all the news links on the websites.

The website has a bunch of links:

```
https://mtonews.com/rihanna-teams-up-with-lvmh-for-fashion-brand    
https://mtonews.com/ciara-goes-naked-for-new-album-release

https://www.btserve.com/serve?t=bidt-sra&amp;v=1&amp;pubId=168&amp;siteId=512&amp;placementUid=5ae8e4105e-168%7C5&amp;pgid=78ff2e45-8b3c-6a06-465f-2ac1a107f4f6&amp;o=https://mtonews.com/&amp    
https://mtonews.com/.image/t_share/MTYzOTYyODY2ODAwNTM1Mzc3/steve_marjorie.png
```

And I want RegEx to open all links similar to the first two.

This is what I have so far:

```
^(?!image$|btserve$).*mtonews.com.*$
```

Answer (score 2):

[This tool](https://regex101.com/r/MWircl/1/) might help you to design your expressions as you wish. Capturing groups are the most simple features of regular expressions, which you can bound your desired outputs with them step by step. For instance,

```
^((https?.*)(mtonews.com\/)([A-Za-z0-9-]+))$
```

has four capturing groups, one for protocol, one for domain, one for leading URLs, and the first one which wraps all these three groups in it, and can be simply called by `$1`.

[image]

#### RegEx Descriptive Graph

The graph visualize how it works and you might want to test other expressions in this [link](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### Basic Performance Test

This JavaScript snippet returns runtime of a 1-million times `for` loop for performance.

```js
const repeat = 1000000;
const start = Date.now();

for (var i = repeat; i >= 0; i--) {
 const string = 'https://mtonews.com/rihanna-teams-up-with-lvmh-for-fashion-brand';
 const regex = /^((https?.*)(mtonews.com\/)([A-Za-z0-9-]+))$/gm;
 var match = string.replace(regex, "\nGroup #1: $1\nGroup #2: $2 \nGroup #3: $3 \nGroup #4: $4 \n");
}

const end = Date.now() - start;
console.log("YAAAY! \"" + match + "\" is a match  ");
console.log(end / 1000 + " is the runtime of " + repeat + " times benchmark test.  ");
```

You can simply modify and simplify this expression.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly

`^(?!.*(?:image|btserve)).*mtonews\.com.*$`

https://regex101.com/r/n2ckJC/1

```
 ^                             # BOS
 (?!                           # Assert
      .* 
      (?: image | btserve )         # Does not contain eiher of these
 )
 .* mtonews \. com .* $        # Must contain this domain
```

Answer (score 1):

In your pattern `^(?!image$|btserve$).*mtonews.com.*$` you use a negative lookahead which assert that the string does not start with images or btserve followed by the end of the string.

That is true for all the examples, and because they all contain mtonews.com they will all match.

If you want to match urls that start with the http protocol and the url `mtonews.com/` using the negative lookahead `(?!\.image)` to make sure what follows is not `.image` you can place it after the forward slash:

```
^https?://mtonews\.com/(?!\.image).*$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `https?://` Match the start with optional s
- `mtonews\.com/` Match mtonew.com followed by a forward slash and escape the dot to match it literally
- `(?!\.image)` Negative lookahead, assert what is directly on the right is not .image
- `.*` Match any char except a newline till the end of the string
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sybVBx/1)

Note that you can replace `.*$` with [`\S+$`](https://regex101.com/r/sybVBx/2) to match non whitespace chars for the url because the dot also matches a space.